How attach a POST Policy to create a PreSigned URL for upload to S3 using the .Net SDK?
When working with the AWS S3 service in .NET, generating a pre-signed URL for file uploads is a common task. However, while the AWS SDK for .NET provides functionality to generate pre-signed URLs using the GetPreSignedURL method, there seems to be a lack of documentation or examples demonstrating how to include a POST policy with the request.
The .Net SDK documentation shows an example ( GetPreSignedURL sample 4 ) to generate a pre signed URL but not to include a Post Policy and neither the GetPreSignedUrlRequest object has that option.
// Create a client
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client();

// Create a CopyObject request
GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
{
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5)
};

// Get path for request
string path = client.GetPreSignedURL(request);

// Retrieve buckets
string allBuckets = GetContents(path);

For example, the NodeJS SDK allows to pass a Conditions parameter to create the Post Policy https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-s3-presigned-post/
const Conditions = [{ acl: "bucket-owner-full-control" }, { bucket: "johnsmith" }, ["starts-with", "$key", "user/eric/"]];

const client = new S3Client({ region: "us-west-2" });
const Bucket = "johnsmith";
const Key = "user/eric/1";
const Fields = {
  acl: "bucket-owner-full-control",
};
const { url, fields } = await createPresignedPost(client, {
  Bucket,
  Key,
  Conditions,
  Fields,
  Expires: 600, //Seconds before the presigned post expires. 3600 by default.
});

However, translating this functionality to the .NET SDK remains unclear.
How can a POST policy be attached to create a pre-signed URL for uploading files to S3 using the .NET SDK? Any insights, examples, or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I tried to pass the conditions as the Parameters to the GetPreSignedUrlRequest object, but that created the URL as x-Policy not Policy, and the v4 signature generated is incorrect

This seems an open issue in GitHub. Responses on this issue might help you. Here is the link to GitHub issue. People have provided their own implementations.
